# Is there a WYSIWYG option for IntelliJ IDEA when creating a GUI? (Like netbeans)

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, wysiwyg

Been attempting to see if I can find a way to edit the gui form in the IntelliJ IDEA in a WYSIWYG format (pretty much the same as netbeans basically) is this possible?

If not, are you able to point me towards a reliable resource to learn how to learn to create an effective GUI layout (can either be book or online)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a `Form Designer` in IntelliJ.

Please refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4jMzEGMKfg)

PS - go to `Plugins` first and ensure `UI Designer` is enabled.